# Reading/Writing a large symmetric matrix in Numpy

Tags: numpy

I have a large (bigger than half of my RAM) n-by-n symmetric matrix S. I want to write it to disk, using only ~n^2/2 space and be able to read it later. The writing part is:

```
S[np.tril_indices(n)].tofile(fid)
```

and the reading:

```
S = np.zeros((n,n))
S[np.tril_indices(n)]=np.fromfile(fid)
S = S + np.tril(S, -1).T
```

The problem is that all the temporary arrays i am creating do not fit in memory

Comment: do you have the problem also in writing?

Comment: maybe try numpy.savez_compressed

Comment: @gg349 yes. as i understand, S[np.tril_idices(n)] creates a copy

Comment: @dnalow The size of the result of savez_compressed on S itself is bigger than n^2/2*8 (8 for float64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case a plain Python loop seems to be the fastest and simplest solution. Also faster than the vectorized approach when that does fit into memory, at least in my testing on Numpy 1.8.2 and a not so fast hard drive as storage medium. So you could consider:

```python
with open('test.dat', 'wb') as fid:
    for i in range(n):
        S[i,i:].tofile(fid)
```

And:

```python
S = np.empty((n, n))
with open('test.dat', 'rb') as fid:
    for i in range(n):
        data = np.fromfile(fid, count=n-i)
        S[i,i:] = data
        S[i:,i] = data
```